# PHPExcel - How to make part of the text bold

Tags: php, phpexcel

How do you create a bold cell value using PHPExcel? I know I can use \n to add a carriage return within the text, but is there some kind of way to bold part of cell value? I also have tried using html formatting such as <b> or <strong> but it did not work.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can bold part of the text in a cell using rich text formatting, as described in section 4.6.37 of the developer documentation.

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$objRichText->createText('This text is ');

$objBold = $objRichText->createTextRun('bold');
$objBold->getFont()->setBold(true);

$objRichText->createText(' within the cell.');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A18')->setValue($objRichText);
```

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for your answer, this is working for Excel2007 object writer. But it cannot working for excel5.

Comment: Rich text isn't yet supported for the Excel5 Writer

Comment: Thanks for the the info and thanks for the great PHPExcel library.

Comment: Support for Rich Text in the Excel5 Writer was added in version 1.7.7 (2012-05-19)

Comment: Good. I have the following code. It sets data statically. It happens one case of 100  produces broken excel file.  http://paste.debian.net/170182/  If I removed this code - no problem happens. The problem is that we want text in the single cell to have different formatting so we can't avoid using richtext. Thanks

Comment: Then ask as a separate question, and post the minimum code to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Thank you. Now Php excel become PHP Spreadsheet, its document is here https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#add-rich-text-to-a-cell

Answer (score 14):

Yes you can bold a cell's value with the following code:

```
$workbook = new PHPExcel;
$sheet = $workbook->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World');
$styleArray = array(
    'font' => array(
        'bold' => true
    )
);
$sheet->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($workbook);
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Hope this helps.

[Source](http://www.codeunit.co.za/2010/07/14/phpexcel-how-to-bold-a-cells-value/)

Comment: It did make the whole cell value to be bold. But that is not what i am looking for. What I was asking is , just to make some part of cell value become bold, let say just "hello" or "world".

Comment: I see, try out @Mark's answer in that case, it looks more appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'world!');
```

for single cell use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

for multiple cells use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:D1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Comment: This will only make the whole value of cell become bold. You need to use RichText as Mark Baker Suggest. And Btw, He is one of PHPExcel Developers.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer even though it doesn't answer OP's question, but it helped for my cause.

Comment: @Ashwin Thanks for your answer. `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setBold(true); I have used your code in PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007. It is working so thank you so much.
`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the HTML helper class in PHPExcel to bold text.

```
$htmlHelper = new \PHPExcel_Helper_HTML();
$html = "<b> Bold Text!! </b>";
$rich_text = $htmlHelper->toRichTextObject($html);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', $rich_text);
```

Comment: This helped me!  The rich text method caused a (recoverable) xml error.

Comment: This is very useful solution, BUT! :) - I`ve got problem with UTF-8 encoding for html code passing trhu Helper_HTML. So, I`ve found this working fix for that case:
$wizard = new PHPExcel_Helper_HTML;
$richText = $wizard->toRichTextObject('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html1);

Answer (score -1):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```