# php_excel / libxl : How to make part of the cell text bold

Tags: php, phpexcel, libxl

With `PHPExcel` library with `RichText` objects, it's possible to set specific styles to some parts of cell text.

An example is given on this post : [PHPExcel - How to make part of the text bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045056/phpexcel-how-to-make-part-of-the-text-bold)

**How to do this with php extension `php_excel based` on `libxl` ?**

Edit : PHPExcel & php_excel are differents, first is a php library, second is a native php extension based on libxl C library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported by lib. This is libXl support answer :

> "unfortunately LibXL doesn't support more than one format in one cell."