# How to Change color of a particular text using phpExcel by reading the text from the cell?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have a text like `Hello World` in a cell.
I want to change Color of the text `World` alone.
I am using **PHPExcel** for creating excel.

I tried the below codes :

```
$objXls                 = new PHPExcel();
$objXls->getActiveSheet($sheetCount)->getStyle($cellCoordinates)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

The result of the above code is like whole text in the cell changed.

I tried `PHPExcel_RichText` also

```
       $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
       $objRichText->createText('World');
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cellCoordinates)->setValue($objRichText);
```

This also didn`t worked.
 Please help me to figure out the issue.
 Thanks

Comment: see this answer...it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277293/set-different-font-color-inside-1-cell-using-phpexcel

Comment: I think createText() in PHPExcel_RichText won't work here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel - How to make part of the text bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045056/phpexcel-how-to-make-part-of-the-text-bold)